# Onenote API failure

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I've got the below error when I have tried to get the Site collection and site IDs. What could be the cause? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var getMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='https://123.sharepoint.com/teams/techs'");

{
  StatusCode: 400,
  ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request',
  Version: 1.1,
  Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
  Headers: {
    OData - Version: 4.0 Cache - Control: private Server: Microsoft - IIS / 8.5 X - AspNet - Version: 4.0.30319 X - Powered - By: ASP.NET X - Powered - By: ASP.NET Date: Sun, 17 Jan 2016 19: 59: 05 GMT Content - Length: 168 Content - Type: application / json;
    charset = utf - 8;
    odata.metadata = minimal;
    odata.streaming = true;
    IEEE754Compatible = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a verbatim code snippet, looks like you're missing the closing parenthesis for the url parameter.

```
var getMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='https://123.sharepoint.com/teams/techs')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing authentication-related headers.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three.aspx

Comment: I have below 3 delegated permissions for the APP  1. Create pages in onenote note book 2. View and modify onenote note books 3.View and modify onenote notebooks in your organization

Comment: Do I need provide any other permissions ?

Comment: If you were using the wrong scopes, the API would let you know in the JSON payload. Could you share the value of the X-CorrelationId header in the HTTP response?

Comment: Do we get X-Correlation Id for this call. I'm not seeing it.  This is the error I see when I Jason parse    "{\r\n  \"error\":{\r\n    \"code\":\"20143\",\"message\":\"The OData query is invalid. Bad Request - Error in query syntax.\",\"@api.url\":\"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20143\"\r\n  }\r\n}"

Comment: Hi Jorge, I have missed a parenthesis in the call. Now it works. Thanks a lot for your help.